# how can I rearrange the ID orders?

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has 500 rows of users, but their ids are something like these now: "7454,21201, 31317..."

I would like to rearrange the ID orders to "1,2,3,4,5....".

What can I do? thanks

It is a column named `id` in `users` table

Comment: Are the users id foreign keys to other tables? What are those tables?

Comment: What difference does it make what the identifiers are?  I don't understand the purpose of modifying them

Comment: no foreign keys to other tables now

Comment: @Martin, just want to make it better looking and easy to know the ids.. any ways can do that? thanks

Comment: @ll I'm still not clear.  Why would an _id_ need to _look better_? It's an internal value that typically conveys no other purpose than uniquely identifying some data. Also, why would you need to know them?

Comment: I have real use of this, do you know how to do that? thanks

Comment: This is not how relational databases work. The (generated) primary key of a row has absolutely not meaning at all. It doesn't matter if the value is 7545 or 1. The only thing it needs to be is unique. If you think you have "real use" for that re-numbering, you should tell us the underlying, real problem you are trying to solve with that. I can not imagine any "real use" for doing that.

Comment: You could drop the id column and re-create it. All the ids should then be reassigned in order.

However this is probably a bad idea in most situations. If you have other tables that have foreign keys to this table then it will definitely not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query. Hope it's help to find your solution

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE `users` SET `users`.`id` = @count:= @count + 1;
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted.  It seems to answer the OP's question.